# When is the value of elliptic integral complex?

Tags: calculus, elliptic-integrals

Are there conditions on $\phi$ and $k$ which determines if the value of elliptic integrals $F(\left.\phi\right| k)$ and $E(\left.\phi\right| k)$ is real or complex?

Comment: What definitions of the elliptic integral do you use?

Comment: I consider the definitions as given in Mathematica https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticF.html

similarly, at https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticE.html

Comment: You may try to see what happens when $k>1$.

Comment: @monk-E I do not see from here how you define the elliptic integrals. In other words: do you multiply $\sin\phi$ by $k$ or by $k^2$?

Comment: i multiply by $k$. Sorry i forgot to mention that the definition is shown when you click on 'details' there.

Comment: yes $k \in R$ and $ \phi \in [0,2\pi]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integrals are real if $k\le1$ or $|\phi|\le\arcsin\frac1{\sqrt{k}}$, assuming that $k$ and $\phi$ are real. Otherwise the integrals are complex.

This boils down to the fact that $\sqrt{1-k\sin^2\phi}$ is real if and only if $1-k\sin^2\phi\ge0.$